# React native background image is just a white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I'm using the ImageBackground component, imported from `react-native`, but no image is showing. It's just a white screen in the background

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.backgroundImage = {image: {uri: "https://i.myImage.com"}}
}

......

<ImageBackground style={styles.container} resizeMode="stretch" source={this.backgroundImage} onError={this.onError.bind(this)}>
    <AdUnit style={styles.bannerAd} />
    <Board  />
</ImageBackground>
```

I've tried changing `this.backgroundImage` to `{image: require('../assets/images/default_seal.jpg')}`

I tried using the resizeMode property [specified by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291704/6331353) but it didn't work.

Comment: in which file is this piece of code? in your Github repo?

Comment: @MarcusMelodious `components/soundboard.js` sorry

Comment: Try setting this directly in your ImageBackground component:
source={require('../assets/images/default_seal.jpg')}
And see it if it displays the image. 

think the problem is on line 222: 
this.backgroundImage = {image:{uri: images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]}}
Not quire sure why you have it like this in your constructor. Looks like you are passing an array to the uri instead of a string.

Comment: Actually, I just saw the images file in your component. If you are passing an image url. You will have to set it like this: source={{ uri: this.backgroundImage }}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer after having a look at the source code.
Make your constructor like this:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.backgroundImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
```

And your ImageBackground component like this:

```
<ImageBackground source={{uri: this.backgroundImage}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageBackground
  source={yourSourceFile}
  style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
> 
    <....yourContent...>
</ImageBackground>
```

If you render the image property on its own is it definitely correct? e.g.

```
{this.backgroundImage}
```

In chrome is the image loading in the network tab, or displaying an error

Do you have any css on the page?  If so can you remove it and re-test it.  Another alternative:

```
<ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } 
                 resizeMode='cover' 
                 source={require('./Your/Path.png')}>
</ImageBackground>
```

The style:

```
imgBackground: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1 
},
```

Comment: My code is already like this, I just have that style saved inside `styles.container`